# delphi tlb_lib file from com component has no connection between interface and object

Tags: delphi, com, interface, delphi-2009

After importing into delphi the com dll file, the delphi in turn generated a lib_tlb.pas file.

Inspecting the file it shows

```
Iinterface1 = interface(IDispatch)
    function func: Integer; safecall;
    procedure proc(param:Iinterface1);
end;

Cointerface1 = class
  class function Create: Iinterface;
  class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): Iinterface1;
end;

Tinterface1 = class(TOleServer)
    function func: Integer;
    procedure proc(param:Iinterface1);
end;
```

Now its clear to see that there is no connection between Tinterface1 and Iinterface1.

The problem comes when one calls proc with an Tinterface1. this will not compile Tinterface1 does not inheritce Iinterface1.

So what suggested to do? change the lib that is auto generated? or do you have a better idea of what to do when wanting to pass Tinterface1 to proc.

The example is a simplification of the code, in the code there is anther object that needs to be the one to be passed to proc, however that proc knows only its interface, which is the same problem.

update: as it seems the manual of the com dll file, says that proc should be

```
    procedure proc(param:^Tinterface1);
```

where the interface is only in delphi point of view.

Comment: You'll need to post the real code.  Have you looked at typelib in typelib viewer?  What should the file show?

Comment: do you recommend on a specific type lib viewer? its a proprietary code , not mine.

Comment: Even just using the typelibrary viewer that comes with Delphi will show you what the structure should be.  Its unlikely the delphi ide is generating the tlb pas incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TInterface1.Proc()` is expecting a pre-existing `IInterface1` object to be passed to it as input.  Use `Cointerface1.Create()` to create that object, eg:

```
var
  intf: Iinterface1;
begin
  intf := Cointerface1.Create;
  TheOleServerInstance.proc(intf);
end;
```

`Tinterface1` is a `TOleServer` descendant that does not directly inherit from `Iinterface1` (but it does wrap an `Iinterface1` internally), so you have to cast it whenever you want to pass it where an `Iinterface1` is expected, eg:

```
var
  intf: Iinterface1;
  svr: Iinterface1;
begin
  intf := Cointerface1.Create;
  if Supports(TheOleServerInstance, Iinterface1, svr) then
    intf.proc(svr);
end;
```

Comment: yes, the object is created with coIntercae1.create, which in turn create Iinterface, that cannot accept Tinterfacce. which makes me wonder, why Delphi bother to create a Tinterface, if it is never been used?

Comment: Read this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Code_Generated_When_You_Import_Type_Library_Information